# which windows API called when execute wmic qfe get hotfixid command?

Tags: windows, debugging, c++, c, api

which windows API called when execute this command

> wmic qfe get hotfixid

command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of APIs are called in this case. wmic is an executable. If you're asking because you want to replace such a command the updates installed on the machine are listed under Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based servicing\Packages. WMI has its own datastores which are probably less useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute command `wmic qfe get hotfixid` from commandline it first execute windows API function `CreateProcessW` with parameters of command and fill path of `wmic.exe`